# Colorize C# console doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, console, colorize

I need to colorize strings by method, so I use `Console.ForegroundColor` property and write text later, but I have made a mistake on somewhere, so all line is one colored. Or is there a better solution? I need to colorize string by &0-&f (hex) and output it to console, here is my solution:

```
    public static void ColorizeConsoleMessage(string message)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(message, "&+[0-9a-f]");
        var split = Regex.Split(message, "&+[0-9a-f]");
        var def = Console.ForegroundColor;
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            switch (match.ToString().Replace("&", "").ToCharArray()[0])
            {
                case '0':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    break;
                case '3': 
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
            }
            Console.Write(split[i]);
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = def;
    }
```

And test: `EventManager.ColorizeConsoleMessage("&4Hello, &6world!");`

Comment: check this for sure - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539193/922198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you were a right the Regex.Matches & Regex.Split together were making things a little awkward, so i combined them

```
    public static void ColorizeConsoleMessage(string message)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message, "&+([0-9a-f])([^&]+)");
        ConsoleColor def = Console.ForegroundColor;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            switch (match.Groups[1].Value[0])
            {
                case '0':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
            }
            string str_to_print = match.Groups[2].Value;
            Console.Write(str_to_print);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = def;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better!

Answer (score 2):

The only fix is did is

```
var i = 1;
```

Regex.Split is creating a empty string element in the split[] which was messing up all the index values

```
    public static void ColorizeConsoleMessage(string message)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message, "&+[0-9a-f]");
        string[] split = Regex.Split(message, "&+[0-9a-f]");
        ConsoleColor def = Console.ForegroundColor;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            switch (match.Value[1])
            {
                case '0':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    break;
                case '5':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    break;
                case '7':
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    break;
            }
            Console.Write(split[i]);
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = def;
    }
```